# Removing loops in R : Case of intersecting polygons

Tags: r

In R, I'm trying to generate a measure of the building footprints that intersect with some circular polygons. For each individual circular polygon on its own, I need the total intersecting area of buildings from a building footprints layer. NOTE some of my circular polygons overlap each other but I need separate individual results so I can't just merge them all together. I have a solution that works where the polygons are are SPatialPolygonsDataFrame but it requires a loop. This is slow and I'm sure inefficient. Is there a better way to do it, using R? Needs to be an R specific solution in this case.

```
for (x in 1:no_of_polygons) {
    
    single_polygon = my_polygons[my_polygons$id==my_polygons$id[x],]

    single_polygon_buildings = gIntersection(buildings_layer,single_polygon)
    if (is.null(single_polygon_buildings) == FALSE){
      agg = aggregate(single_polygon_buildings)
      single_polygon$area = area(agg)
    }
    if (x==1) {
      my_list = list(st_as_sf(single_polygon))
    } else {
      my_list[[length(my_list)+1]] = st_as_sf(single_polygon)
    }
}
single_sf = dplyr::bind_rows(my_list)
```

Sample data [here](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fo/fhphyx12bqr4lbuaqejbu/h?dl=0&rlkey=axnfmir0i2ien4fm7k6fmohqs)

Comment: Could you set up a sample data set for illustration that we can test with (or if possible, share the actual data)? Otherwise we all have to create two sets of test polygons before we can even start thinking about the process.

Comment: All of the functions in your loop can be replaced with sf analogs `sf::st_intersection`, `sf::aggregate` and `sf::st_area`. The subset sy row will also work to subset a single feature `for(x in unique(my_polygons$id))` then subset using `my_polygons[my_polygons$id == x,]`

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the solution here. Yes, I can do that substitution but does that allow me to remove the main loop which is what I'm after? Sorry if I'm not understanding something obvious here

Comment: Its not a solution - if it was a solution it would be in an answer, not a comment. Whatever solution we can come up with will probably be faster with the `sf` package functions over the `sp ` package functions. It might even be fast enough with the loop. We don't know the size of your data or have a sample data set so hard to be more specific.

Comment: Thank you - I understand better now. I shall look at this option.

Comment: I have added a link to sample data